# Rearrange date format jQuery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have a function that generates the date with this format:

`MM-DD-YYYY`

Is there any jquery or javascript trick to convert that value into:

`YYYY-MM-DD`?

#### More Detailed Explanation:

The function I have generates the date and stored in a variable called `tdate`

So `var tdate = 01-30-2001`

I would like to do some jquery or javascript to turn `tdate` into:

`tdate = 2001-01-30`

tdate is a string

Thanks!

Comment: hello I am unsure where you are getting the -2030 and 1970 from

Comment: What is the actual data type of `tdate`?  The lines of code you're showing make it look like you're subtracting integers, which has nothing to do with a date.  Is `tdate` an actual date object?  A string?  Something else?  If it's a date object, why not just format it how you want it when you output it?

Comment: oh yes sorry I need a string!

Comment: @david the datatype of tdate is a string.

Comment: @david I didnt put in my full code, only a small snippet i thought was required to answer the question. Basically I am using an api that needs a certain format and the way i have the user input in a date does not match the api's format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can slice() up the string and put it back together the way you want it

```js
var tdate = '01-30-2001';

tdate = [tdate.slice(-4), tdate.slice(0,5)].join('-');
// or tdate = tdate.slice(-4) + '-' +  tdate.slice(0,5)
 
console.log(tdate)
```

Comment: Awesome, this is the simplest and cleanest answer. I will accept thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can use `.split()`, destructuring assignment, termplate literal to place `yyyy`, `mm`, `dd` in any order

```js
var date = "01-30-2001";

var [mm, dd, yyyy] = date.split("-");

var revdate = `${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd}`;

console.log(revdate)
```

Comment: except that would result in 2001-30-01 ;p

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I upvoted you but accepted someone elses answer because they found a solution with one less variable

Answer (score 6):

You can use a little bit *regex* to capture *year*, *month* and *day* and reorder them:

```js
var tdate = "01-30-2001";

console.log(
  tdate.replace(/^(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})$/, "$3-$1-$2")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can split the string on '-' and then re arrange the array once and join again to form the date.

```js
var date = "01-30-2001";

var arr = date.split("-");
var revdate = arr.splice(-1).concat(arr.splice(0,2)).join('-');
console.log(revdate);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I upvoted you but accepted someone elses answer because they found a solution with one less variable